# Usage of std::unique_ptr in combination with custom free-operations

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a class with a constructor and a destructor and the following code for both:

```
class propagation_module{
    private:
                gsl_interp_accel *xa;
                interp2d_spline *interp_s;
    public:
        propagation_module()
        {
            std::vector<int> p_N = {1, 2, 3}, z_vec = {1, 2, 3};
            xa = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
            interp_s = interp2d_spline_alloc(interp2d_bicubic, p_N.size(), z_vec.size());
        }
        ~propagation_module(){
            gsl_interp_accel_free(xa);
            interp2d_spline_free(interp_s);
        }
}
```

I would like to replace the pointers with std::unique_ptr-variables, but I do not understand how to implement the free-functions. According to some other questions the following way should work:

```
class propagation_module
{
    private: 
        std::unique_ptr<gls_interp_accel, decltype(&gsl_interp_accel_free)> xa;
        std::unique_ptr<interp2d_spline, decltype(&interp2d_spline_free)> interp_s;
    public:
        propagation_module()
        {
            //Same as above
        }
        //No destructor necessary
}
```

Is that correct, or did I forget something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're halfway there. By default, `std::unique_ptr` will default-construct its deleter when none is passed in at `unique_ptr` creation time. You provide the correct types for the deleters, but you need to provide their *values* too:

```
public:
    propagation_module()
    {
        std::vector<int> p_N = {1, 2, 3}, z_vec = {1, 2, 3};
        xa = {gsl_interp_accel_alloc(), &gsl_interp_accel_free};
        interp_s = {interp2d_spline_alloc(interp2d_bicubic, p_N.size(), z_vec.size()), &interp2d_spline_free};
    }
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to have to give the correct deleters each time you create a unique pointer, you can create default-constructible wrappers to call the right function:

```
struct GslInterpAccelFree
{
  void operator() (gsl_interp_accel *p) const { gsl_interp_accel_free(p); }
};

struct Interp2dSplineFree
{
  void operator() (interp2d_spline *p) const { interp2d_spline_free(p); }
};

class propagation_module
{
    private: 
        std::unique_ptr<gls_interp_accel, GslInterpAccelFree> xa;
        std::unique_ptr<interp2d_spline, Interp2dSplineFree> interp_s;
    public:
        propagation_module()
        {
            std::vector<int> p_N = {1, 2, 3}, z_vec = {1, 2, 3};
            xa.reset(gsl_interp_accel_alloc());
            interp_s.reset(interp2d_spline_alloc(interp2d_bicubic, p_N.size(), z_vec.size()));
        }
        //No destructor necessary
}
```